# jQuery/javascript - change image based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have an existing ecommerce page where I have this code for a dropdown menu:

```
<select data-optgroup="10201" class="prodoption detailprodoption" onchange="updateoptimage(0,0)" name="optn0" id="optn0x0" size="1"><option value="">Please Select...</option><option value="102011" class="">Small</option>
<option value="102012" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="102013" class="">Large</option>
<option value="102014" class="">XL</option>
<option value="102015" class="">2XL (+$3.00)</option>
<option value="102016" class="">3XL (+$5.00)</option>
<option value="102017" class="">4XL (+$7.00)</option>
<option value="102018" class="">5XL (+$7.00)</option>
</select>
```

I need to be able to insert an image and have the image change based on the dropdown selection. I know how insert an image using a jquery function, but dont know how to change it. This should be a relatively easy task, but cant seem to figure it out. I think I need to set up an array that matches the values of the dropdowns to the img src that I desire. I'd also like to include a php variable that is generated via PHP if that is possible. Im sure this is a hot mess, but any direction I can get is appreciated.

```
var phpcode = [ <?php = ...... ?> ]
var pictureList = 
    [ '10211' , 'images/sample1'],
    [ '10212' , 'images/sample2'],
    [ '10213' , 'images/sample3'],
    [ '10214' , 'images/sample4'],
    [ '10215' , 'images/sample5'];


$('.detailprodoption').change(function () {
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[],phpcode[],".jpg");
});
```

I need the final output to be something like "images/sample5-phpcode.jpg

Comment: missing a 0 in all entries in your pictureList.  should be 102**0**11

Comment: `I'd also like to include a php variable` include where?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way will be to add some `data-` attribute to your select `option`s. Like:

```
<select data-optgroup="10201" class="prodoption detailprodoption">
    <option value="1000" data-img-src="some/path/img1.jpg">value</option>
    <option value="1001" data-img-src="some/path/img2.jpg">value</option>
    <option value="1002" data-img-src="some/path/img3.png">value</option>
    <!-- More options here -->
</select>
```

After that your `change` can be, for example:

```
$('.detailprodoption').change(function () {
    $('img').attr("src", $( this ).find( "option:selected" ).data( "img-src" ));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to generate a valid data structure for `pictureList` as what you have now is invalid. The follwoing is probably what you were after.

```
var phpcode = "whatisthis";
//Generate a proper data structure
var pictureList = {
    '102012': 'images/sample2',
    '102013': 'images/sample3',
    '102014': 'images/sample4',
    '102015': 'images/sample5',
    '102016': 'images/sample6',
    '102017': 'images/sample7',
    '102018': 'images/sample8'
};

$('.detailprodoption').change(function() {
    //Set image src when the selected value isn't empty
    $('img').attr({
        "src": this.value && [pictureList[this.value], "-", phpcode, ".jpg"].join("") || ""
    });
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8tyf2a7/) for the above code.